# Convert an EXE and its dependencies into one stand-alone EXE

Tags: python, compilation, exe, cx-freeze

I'm using cx_Freeze to compile Python programs into executables and it works just fine, but the problem is that it doesn't compile the program into one EXE, it converts them into a `.exe` file AND a whole bunch of `.dll` files including `python32.dll` that are necessary for the program to run.

Does anyone know how I can package all of these files into one `.exe` file? I would rather it be a plain EXE file and not just a file that copies the DLLs into a temporary directory in order to launch the program.

**EDIT:** This is in reference to Python 3

Comment: cx_Freeze doesn't support that yet. You can make an installer, but not a standalone 'just run this' exe

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options: **PyInstaller** or **py2exe**.

With py2exe, there's an option called [bundle_files](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable), that you can set:

- **3** (default): Don't bundle.
- **2**: Bundle everything but the Python interpreter.
- **1**: Bundle everything, including the Python interpreter.

Here is a sample **setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "single.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

This approach does not require extracting files to a temporary location.

Comment: unfortunately, py2exe only works for python 2.x, and not python 3.x. But, thanks for the info. I've updated the question to show I need an answer for python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller is usually  the easier option when compiling a python script into one file.

```
pyinstaller.py program.py --onefile
```

See the documentation here: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw

Comment: I checked it out and I don't believe this is updated for Python 3 either. Good info though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried innosetup? It can create installer files from the output of cxfreeze. There might be an option somewhere to bundle everything into one file.